# Github in Parent Directory of Google Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

I'm a noob to Google Colab and Python. I'm attempting to import a custom set of scripts from a Github directory. I'm using the following:

```
!git clone https://github.com/theAIGuysCode/tensorflow-yolov4-tflite.git
```

By default, this will export to a folder that it names based on the git name. However, the functions in the needed scripts call the parent directory and not the git folder name. Example:

[Google Colab Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYtNe.png)

Is there a method for importing the git in the parent directory so the scripts can run without modifying the file hierarchy in each script?

Answer (score 0):

The error is that you are in a different directory. Most likely current directory is `/content/` if those two cells in the picture are on top.

You need to change directory before you can call `save_model.py`, then it will work as expected. Use `!pwd` to know the current directory.

Before the last cell change directory to the one where desired code is. So in this case it can be,

```
%cd "/content/tensorflow-yolov4-tflite"
```

If you are unsure about path, right click on folder and select `Copy path` to use with `cd` command.